# Using the Entity Framework to retrieve a generic collection from a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently helping someone with upgrading a project from MongoDB to MS SQL; the Entity Framework has been used extensively throughout the code, and as quickly as I attempt to come up to speed on it, I must admit that I am still feeling slightly vexed by it. I understand that it can be used to automatically map relationships between classes and various columns inside a database, but beyond this, I know little. I am more used to the older way of manually settings up relationships using ADO, so this is a new experience for me.

Once piece of code in particular, a method, that seems the crux of the upgrade scheme, is what I am having some trouble creating an analogue that is compatible with MS SQL. The code is below:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetCollection<T>(ColName collectionName)
        {
            MongoDatabase database = GetDatabase();
            MongoCollection<T> collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName.ToString());
            return collection.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Normally, I'd just copy the column names from the database, and set the fields inside a new object, and return a list of them. Except in this case, it's a Generic / Template, and I imagine that Entity does some magic that automatically maps the fields inside an object according to what it finds in the database. Unfortunately, that is as far as I can go. I'm reading the tutorials / other questions on this site, but this one seems a bit over my head, using something I have no experience with. Perhaps a Linq statement of some design might work here? Or something more manual...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have implemented repository pattern using Entity Framework. So, if you have `DatabaseContext` as the type of your implementation of `DbContext`. You can do that as below:

```
public partial class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
        private IDbSet<T> _entities;

        public Repository(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }
        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetCollection()
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Entities;
            }
        }
   }
```